# Run untrusted Mach-O file?

Tags: macos, compilation, trusted

I have a question regarding Mac.

Is it possible to run untrusted Mach-O file?

Can I compile a code without a certificate and run it on Mac computer?

or the GateKeeper will block it?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can just compile and run C/C++/whatever code, e.g. from the command line, and run it. What problem did you encounter ?

Comment: So I don't understand what is the purpose of GateKeeper? Isn't it to prevent such cases?

Comment: I think it's mainly to prevent malicious apps from being launched from the Finder or from other apps/scripts/installers. Presumably the command line is not a concern, since if you have access to the command line then you can do pretty much anything you like anyway. (I'm just guessing, BTW - I don't have any actual evidence for this, other than knowing that I can build and run code from the command line without interference...)